# Resize svg file in steps to avoid blurriness

Tags: css, svg

so I though about using svg files for icons.
for e.g. like this

```
.icon-page{
    background-image: url("../../layout/icons.svg");
    background-size: 2em 2em;
}
```

I would like it to scale with the font-size of the user, which is why I figured I use em.
But if the users default font-size is something like 23px or so, the svg is all blurry because the icons can not fit perfectly into the pixels. Is there a way to get around that? Can I detect the users font-size with a mediaquery and set the icon font-size to a certain value to make sure the icons look okay?

Comparison 22px (bad/blurry) to 24px (correct)

[image]
[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TgHLf/17/

Comment: Can you show a demo on jsfiddle.net or something? Not really understanding the problem.

Comment: Just added to pictures to make the problem clear.

Comment: OK I get that, but can you do a demo so we can play with the code as well.

Comment: You should be able to play with it here. Change the body font-size to see the blurriness. http://jsfiddle.net/TgHLf/17/

Comment: The default font size for browsers is generally 16px.  I think it is probably pretty uncommon that people change that.  Are you sure it's worth going to all that effort to avoid a little anti-aliasing?

Comment: I disagree. I think many people who's eyesight is not so good change their default font-size. If you know a study proving me wrong, please send me a link, because I have no research to prove my point. But I think it is not necessarily so much work, once one figures out how it could work.

Comment: This is what it looks like for me at 22 and 24. http://i.imgur.com/ucKHKTH.png I'm not seeing the same blurriness as you. :/ Latest Chrome stable on Win 8

Comment: Do you have a highres screen? It is much more visible on normal screens. But you can easily replicate the effect in illustrator. Its depending on the icon of course. If the lines of the icon don't fit into the pixel grid (e.g. a line is on 30.5px) it gets antialised becauese there are no half pixels. This leads to blurriness.